# java.lang.unsatisfiedLinkError .so lib Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to load a .so lib that someone gave to me, but I'm getting this error:

> Warning - No implementation found for native Lmy/pack/Native.init()
>   Error- java.lang.unsatisfiedLinkError: init

I put the lib in libs/armeabi